# Choose the correct file ending for dynamic libraries regardless of platform

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake 2.8.8 and the `ExternalProject` module. CMake retrieves the project's source files and builds them correctly (resulting in `project.a` and `project.so` files on unix). I want to always go with the dynamic library. How can I do that and still be cross platform?

I tried

```
list(
    APPEND foo_LIBRARIES
    ${binary_dir}/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}project${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}
)
```

but that does not work because `{CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}` is a list of `.a;.so`.

```
list(
    APPEND foo_LIBRARIES
    ${binary_dir}/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}project.so
)
```

works, but only on unix systems. Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that for `WIN32` the `${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}` is just `.lib`, you could do something like:

```
set(ProjectSuffix ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
list(REMOVE_ITEM ProjectSuffix .a)
list(APPEND foo_LIBRARIES
    ${binary_dir}/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}project${ProjectSuffix})
```